# Is the following inequality true $(a^3-b^6)^3+(3abc)^3 \leq (a^3-b^6+3cb^3)^3$?

Tags: inequality, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be all positive integers greater than $1$.

If $$a>b^2$$ and $$a^3-b^6> 3c$$ Is this the following inequality true?: 
  $$(a^3-b^6)^3+(3abc)^3 \leq (a^3-b^6+3cb^3)^3$$ I tried to expand without much success. Any Hints?

Comment: $(5,2,11)$ seems to be a counter-example.

Comment: [Have a look here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%5E3%E2%88%92b%5E6%29%5E3%2B%283abc%29%5E3%E2%89%A4%28a%5E3%E2%88%92b%5E6%2B3cb%5E3%29%5E3%2Ca%3Eb%5E2%2Ca%5E3-b%5E6%3E3c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. There are infinitely many counterexamples.

For $(a,b,c)=(k^3,k,k^5)\ (k\ge 2\in\mathbb Z)$,
one has 
$$a-b^2=k^3-k^2=k^2(k-1)\gt 0$$
and
$$a^3-b^6-3c=k^9-k^6-3k^5=k^5(k^4-k-3)\ge k^5(2^4-2-3)\gt 0,$$
but
$$(a^3-b^6)^3+(3abc)^3-(a^3-b^6+3cb^3)^3$$
$$=(k^9-k^6)^3+(3k^9)^3-(k^9-k^6+3k^8)^3$$
$$=9k^{20}(k-1)^2(k^2+k+1)(3k^3+(k-1)(k+1)+k(k-1))\color{red}{\gt} 0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $a=10$, $b=3$ and $c=89$, we have:
$$a=10\quad >\quad b^2=9$$
$$a^3-b^6=271\quad >\quad 3c=267$$
But:
$$(a^3-b^6)^3+(3abc)^3=513,942,303,511 \not\le (a^3-b^6+3cb^3)^3=418,508,992,000$$
Hence the inequality is false.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

I can simplify  the inequality by the following equivalent transformations:

$$(a^3-b^6)^3+(3abc)^3 \leq (a^3-b^6+3cb^3)^3$$

Put $A=a^3-b^6$.

$$A^3+(3abc)^3 \leq (A+3cb^3)^3$$

$$(3abc)^3 \leq (A+3cb^3)^3-A^3$$
$$(3abc)^3 \leq (3cb^3)((A+3cb^3)^2+(A+3cb^3)A+A^2) $$
$$9a^3c^2 \leq (A+3cb^3)^2+(A+3cb^3)A+A^2$$
$$9a^3c^2 \leq A^2+6Acb^3+9c^2b^6+A^2+3Acb^3+A^2$$
$$9a^3c^2 \leq 3A^2+9Acb^3+9c^2b^6$$
$$3a^3c^2 \leq A^2+3Acb^3+3c^2b^6$$
$$0 \leq A^2+3Acb^3+3c^2(b^6-a^3)$$
$$0 \leq A^2+3Acb^3-3c^2A$$
Since $A>0$, we can divide by $A$:
$$ 0 \leq A+3cb^3-3c^2$$
$$ 0 \leq a^3-b^6+3cb^3-3c^2.$$